# Avoid a SQL subquery double join on the right element in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I am trying to optimize a sql query and want to see how i can avoid subqueries when doing a second join on the resulting table. I have the following query from the dvd rental database provided by postgresql and have joined three tables with the purpose of getting the category of the film. I know that I can use a CTE or temp table but I was wondering if there was a shorter route to accomplish what is below:

```
--------get the category of a film
--------link film table to category id table with film id
--------then link resulting table to the category name table with category_id
SELECT
t1.title,
t1.film_id,
t1.category_id,
c.name
FROM
(
SELECT 
f.title,
f.film_id,
fc.category_id
FROM
film as f 
left join film_category as fc on f.film_id = fc.film_id     
    ) as T1 left join category as c on t1.category_id = c.category_id
ORDER by title
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you have any subqueries at all:

```
SELECT f.title, f.film_id, fc.category_id, c.name
FROM film f LEFT JOIN
     film_category fc 
     ON f.film_id = fc.film_id LEFT JOIN   
     category c 
     ON fc.category_id = c.category_id
ORDER by f.title
```

Comment: thanks, this is what i was looking for. I will upvote asap